# What is the regular expression to delete HTML comments?

Tags: iphone, html, regex, xcode, replace

I need to remove several thousand comments from an HTML document. The comments are in this form (multi-line):

```
<p>some HTML</p>
<!--
  FOO
  BAR
  BLAH
-->
<p>more HTML</p>
```

What regular expression can I use in a find/replace to return this result:

```
<p>some HTML</p>
<p>more HTML</p>
```

Comment: duplicate possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Dreamweaver, the "Clean Up HTML/XHTML" command has an option to remove Non-Dreamweaver comments.  That should take care of a problem like this very easily.

Comment: I know I asked for a regex, but this was actually the fastest and easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to remove comments in this particular format (and leave all other comments intact):

```
replace(/^<\!--.*?-->$/mg, "")
```

The .*? is non-aggressive match.  "m" flag necessary to make it multi-line (so ^ and $ will match the beginning/end of lines respectively).

If you want to remove *all* comments:

```
replace(/<\!--.*?-->/g, "")
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `-` (except in `[]`)

Comment: Thanks. :-) Sometimes I forget which characters need escaping where, so just escape them all...  Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt use Regex for this. Try the HTML agility pack instead.
[HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)